# Numpad not working in Vim, but working in Bash and other parts of OS?

Tags: vim, keyboard

Number pad is not working in `vim`. Number pad works fine in Bash and within the terminal session. Application Keypad Mode is disabled in PuTTY (Normal). Never had this problem before. Also, checked `/etc/vimrc` and it seems fine. There seems to be no `vimrc` override running. OS is BSD.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7274961/using-numpad-in-vi-vim-via-putty.

Comment: Putty is already set correctly. This part interests me, but I don't quite understand it: "If using ssh through terminal you can just go to Edit > Num Lock (Third from bottom). It needs to have a checkmark to the left of it."

Comment: Right, I realized you already had it, it was that first A'er regarding the SSH that caught my eye for you to investigate.

Comment: It's quite cryptic, to me at least. :/